# WP8 application running in background

Tags: windows-phone-8, background-agents, background-application

I'm trying to learn how to create an application on Windows Phone 8. I followed this [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662935%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) published on msdn.

The problem is that this code doesn't work,and i don't know why. I tried to debug it. So far, i found that  the problem is `Application_RunningInBackground` method  is never triggered. Normally, it's supposed to start working when apps works in the background. Or, am i missing something ?

Comment: "It doesn't work". Could you be more precise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WP8 doesn't support for multitaking for apps in the background. In WP8 a few additions were made to the WP multitasking story. The one you're referring to is "GeoLocation background tracking apps". As you might be deduce from the name, it's only useful for apps that track geolocation in the background.

Geolocation background tracking apps must declare themselves as such in the wmAppManfiest.xml, Have a working GeoLocator reporting GeoLoc back to the app and first be launched by the user. The optimal usecase here is an app like Nokia Drive which consumers would want to start and have those keep working in the background.

Note, using Geolocation background multitaking for non-geolocation tasks is a violation of the certification guidelines and Microsoft is tracking usage of this wmAppManfiest.xml for abuse.